# JavaScript BitArray Implementation

Tags: javascript, array

I am working on a project in which an array can easily grow beyond 50M in length. It's an array holding only boolean (`0`/`1`) values. Using `Uint8Array` is just fine and it's very performant compared normal arrays. Still I just wanted to try implementing a `BitArray` by extending `DataView` object. `BitArray` enormously reduces the memory footprint compared to normal Arrays (1/32) and `Uint8Array` (1/8). So that's a certain gain but as for speed, despite I did everything to my knowledge `BitArray` is still slightly slower compared to both unless the size hits the 33,554,433 limit (> 2²⁵). [As I have read from this document](https://itnext.io/v8-deep-dives-understanding-array-internals-5b17d7a28ecc), at this point the normal `Array` reaches to ~268MB memory limit and it's internal structure gets switched to `NumberDictionary[16]` yielding a dramatic slow down in v8. Note that when the length is 33,554,433 the `BitArray` uses only 4MB of memory.

One other point to note is, for my application i need the total number of 1s in the `BitArray` (population count) which is the `popcount` property in below code. Thanks to the blazingly fast [Hamming Weight algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) `BitArray` is like 80 times faster compared to counting the existing items in array though I am not testing it here.

Any ideas to boost the `BitArray` up a little are most welcome.

```js
class BitArray extends DataView{

  constructor(n,ab){
    var abs = n >> 3; // ArrayBuffer Size
    super(ab instanceof ArrayBuffer ? ab
                                    : n & 31 ? new ArrayBuffer(abs + 4 - (abs & 3))
                                             : new ArrayBuffer(abs));
  }

  get length(){
    return this.buffer.byteLength*8;
  }

  get popcount(){
    var m1  = 0x55555555,
        m2  = 0x33333333,
        m4  = 0x0f0f0f0f,
        h01 = 0x01010101,
        pc  = 0,
        x;
    for (var i = 0, len = this.buffer.byteLength >> 2; i < len; i++){
       x = this.getUint32(i << 2);
       x -= (x >> 1) & m1;             //put count of each 2 bits into those 2 bits
       x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2); //put count of each 4 bits into those 4 bits
       x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4;        //put count of each 8 bits into those 8 bits
       pc += (x * h01) >> 56;
    }
    return pc;
  }

  // n >> 3 is Math.floor(n/8)
  // n & 7 is n % 8

  at(n){  
    return this.getUint8(n >> 3) & (1 << (n & 7)) ? 1 : 0;
  }

  set(n){
    this.setUint8(n >> 3, this.getUint8(n >> 3) | (1 << (n & 7)));
  }

  reset(n){
    this.setUint8(n >> 3, this.getUint8(n >> 3) & ~(1 << (n & 7)));
  }

  slice(a = 0, b = this.length){
    return new BitArray(b-a,this.buffer.slice(a >> 3, b >> 3));
  }

  toggle(n){
    this.setUint8(n >> 3, this.getUint8(n >> 3) ^ (1 << (n & 7)));
  }

  toString(){
    return new Uint8Array(this.buffer).reduce((p,c) => p + Array.prototype.reduce.call(c.toString(2).padStart(8,"0"),(f,s) => s+f), "")
                                      .slice(0,this.length);
  }
}

// Test code starts from here

var len = 1e6,  // array length
    tst = 10,   // test count
    arr = Array(len),
    bar = new BitArray(len),
    uia = new Uint8Array(len),
    r1,r2,r3,t = 0;

console.log(`There are ${bar.popcount} 1s in the BitArray`);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
  (Math.random() > 0.5) && ( t++
                           , bar.set(i)
                           );
}

console.log(`${t} .set() ops are made and now there are ${bar.popcount} 1s in the BitArray`);

console.time("Array");
for (var k = 0; k < tst; k++){
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) arr[i] = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) t = arr[1];
  r1 = arr.slice();
}
console.timeEnd("Array");

console.time("BitArray");
for (var k = 0; k < tst; k++){
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) Math.random() > 0.5 ? bar.set(i) : bar.reset(i)
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) t = bar.at(i);
  r2 = bar.slice();
}
console.timeEnd("BitArray");

console.time("Uint8Array");
for (var k = 0; k < tst; k++){
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) uia[i] = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) t = uia[i];
  r3 = uia.slice();
}
console.timeEnd("Uint8Array");
```

Comment: Would be handy to include a few unit tests. I was thinking of playing around with the code, but first I would have to add tests to make sure I actually help and don't break anything at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `abs + 4 - (abs & 3)`

Could be simplified: `(abs + 3) & -4`

They are not equivalent expressions, but they are equivalent when `abs` is not a multiple of 4. Actually the simpler one is more convenient in this case: with this expression, you can skip the ternary, because it won't improperly round up multiples of 4 so that's no longer a special case.

### popcount trickery

You're using a good trick already, but there is still a possibility for more. One interesting property of the trick you used is that when it has done a couple of steps, it starts to waste some of its potential, by which I mean for example that the third step, `(x + (x >> 4)) & m4`, adds adjacent nibbles, but the values in those nibbles range from 0 to 4 (inclusive), not the range 0 to 15. If the loop was unrolled a factor of two, then instead of having two whole copies of the popcount trick, only the first half needs to be duplicated: then the intermediate results could be added (producing nibbles with values in the range 0 to 8, inclusive), and the second half of the trick (the third and fourth steps) needs only to be performed once.

There are more tricks, for example given 3 uint32s (`a, b, c`), we only need 2 32-bit popcounts to count all the bits:

```
b0 = a ^ b ^ c
b1 = (a & (b | c)) | (b & c)
count = popcount(b0) + 2 * popcount(b1)
```

The bit-manipulation steps are effectively a bit-level 3-input addition, with the 2-bit result spread across two variables: at each position, `b0` holds bit 0 of the sum at that position, `b1` holds bit 1 of the sum. This can be generalized to combining 7 inputs into 3, 15 into 4, etc. Even better versions of this idea can be found in [Faster Population Counts Using
AVX2 Instructions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07612.pdf) (of course you won't be using AVX2 in JavaScript, but some of the same techniques can be applied to reduce the number of actual popcounts).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One point is, regardless the demanded `BitArray` size it should be a multiple of 32 as I make sequential 32 bit readings for the `popcount` function. The excess bits are zero anyways. In other words if the demanded size is 100 bits then I have to arange 128 bits (16 bytes) at least. Here `abs` is just the base that I have to calculate the extra number bytes needed to make the total number of bits a multiple of 32. Otherwise your information and the linked paper is very interesting. I will study them hoping to improve the `popcount` functionality.

Comment: @Redu I'm not sure what you mean, you're rounding up the count and so does the alternative I presented. Same thing (in this context), just simpler. You can write it as `((n + 31) & -32) >> 3` also and skip `abs`.

Comment: Now seeing this, obviously my implementation seems so naive. Honestly it took me a while to grasp  `((n + 31) & -32) >> 3` but this seems to be exactly how this job is supposed to be implemented or perhaps `((n + 31) & ~31) >> 3`. Rockstar.